# Installing Nvidia 610m 2gb from root

Tags: installation, drivers, nvidia

I've read some answers regarding on how to install the nvidia driver. I followed those steps but got a problem when I ran it in the terminal.

This is the error:

ERROR: You appear to be running an X server; please exit X before
installing. For further details, please see the section INSTALLING
THE NVIDIA DRIVER in the README available on the Linux driver
download page at www.nvidia.com.

You're help will be very much appreciated! :)

Update: The laptop is optimus enabled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

Answer (score 1):

First nvidia 610m is configured as optimus by most manufacturer. **If your system is optimus enabled. Please don't install nvidia drivers from the nvidia site** It will cause your system to boot in non-GUI mode (black screen)

For your question's answer. You need to stop X server.

- Press Alt+Ctrl+F1
- login using your user name and password
- enter `sudo stop lightdm`
- Now proceed with the driver installation
- On complete you might need to reboot.

*Let me know if you are running in optimus system. I will post instructions.**Please don't install nvidia drivers from nvidia site if you have an optimus enabled system***

Comment: im running in optimus system

Comment: The you should install bumblebee. Follow here http://askubuntu.com/q/36930/35775